# how to pass the current item to the function so that i can remove it from array in react component?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I just cant pass the current item in the function because I have an click event in the "X" which is a different node, so i always get item passed as X and not the item in the array. I was thinking about making it a different component and import it, but I just wanted to see if I have  something here, how would I go about deleting. So my main issue is how to pass the current item in the array. Here is my code

```
export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        fruits: ["apple", "orange", "mango", "banana"],
        name: "Micheal"
    }
    // this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);

}

delItem(item) {
    console.log('Click happened');
    console.log(item)
    //console.log(item.target.innerText) //x
    console.log(this.state.fruits)
    var newList = this.state.fruits.filter(val => {
        return item != val
    })
    console.log(newList);
    // this.setState({
    //     fruits : newList
    // })

}

render() {
    var fruitsList = this.state.fruits.map(item => {
        return (
            <li>
                <h1> {item} </h1>
                <p className="del-btn" onClick={this.delItem.bind(this)}> x </p>
            </li>
        )
    })

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <h1> Hello {this.state.name} from inside a component </h1>
                <About></About>
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {fruitsList}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
 }
}


render(<App name="Milan" />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: `onClick={this.delItem.bind(this, item)}`

Comment: oh man, thanks a lot, I missed that in the Handling Events documentation at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

Well, You can choose to send item ref directly in function onClick - `this.delItem.bind(this, item)`

```
delItem(item) {
   let fruits= this.state.fruits;

   function findFruit(element, index, array){
        return element==item;
   }

   let index = fruits.findIndex(findFruit);
   fruits.splice(index,1);
   this.setState({fruits : fruits});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your delItem function to be higher order... You can have delItem() be a function that returns a function, and that function can use a parameter passed to the delItem() function... Pass the fruit!

```
delItem = (fruit) => () => {
  console.log('Click happened');
  console.log(item)

  // delete your fruit
}
```

Then bind onClick as follows:

```
<p className="del-btn" onClick={this.delItem(item)}> x </p>
```